# Add Custom NSView into NSStackView

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have a Custom **NSView**. This view had a xib with all desing

```
import Cocoa

class CustomView: NSView {

@IBOutlet var contentView: NSView!

override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
    super.init(frame: frameRect)
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, topLevelObjects: nil)
    addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.frame = contentView.bounds
    contentView.autoresizingMask = [.height, .width]

}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)

    // Drawing code here.
}

}
```

When I try to add this view into **NSStackView** doesn't work.

This is the code in my **ViewController**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let view = CustomView()
    self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)

}
```

Any idea.

Comment: `contentView.frame = self.bounds` instead of `contentView.frame = contentView.bounds`? Is `CustomView` supposed to add another `CustomView` as subview? Please describe "doesn't work".

Comment: contentView is a view inside the CustomView. But I don't know how to add a ny custom view into NSStackView. Do you have any example about this. @Willeke